# symfony 3.2.4 ... Unable to find template "OCPlatformBundle:Advert:index.html.twig

Tags: symfony, templates

I am using symfony 3.2.4 (got with console --version).
I am working the openclassroom tutorial.
That controller always return the error below.
Nevertheless, the file below exist with and is accessible.

`src/OC/PlatformBundle/Resources/views/Advert/index.html.twig`

I got crazy with that. Does someone have an idea ?

Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
// src/OC/PlatformBundle/Controller/AdvertController.php
namespace OC\PlatformBundle\Controller;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
class AdvertController extends Controller
{
  public function indexAction()
  {
    $content = $this->get('templating')->render('OCPlatformBundle:Advert:index.html.twig');

    return new Response($content);
  }
}
```

> Unable to find template "OCPlatformBundle:Advert:index.html.twig"
>   (looked into: /var/www/html/symfony/app/Resources/views,
>   /var/www/html/symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form).

*

Comment: It is almost like your bundle was not registered in `AppKernel`, but that would not make sense, wouldn't it?

Comment: And don't forget to clean the cache! (twig have to be compiled to php by symfony and putted in cache)

Comment: yeah the bubdle is registered and the controller is working, while it return a string response and not a render content. I clean the cache via the console (this was well done because i had to replace the 777 right on the /var/dev folder) but this change nothing.... :/

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to create your template in `app/Resources/views/Advert/index.html.twig` ?

This is a better practice : `Store all your application's templates in app/Resources/views/ directory.` (From SF doc)...

So, you'll be able to "call" it by this way:

```
/***/
public function indexAction()
{
    return $this->render('Advert/index.html.twig', []);
}
/***/
```